# How to determine the minimum thickness for a Red Dot Sight mount built in aluminum?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, aluminum

I'm designing what is called a "Red Dot Sight Mount" (see image below) for a handgun.

**Disclaimer:** this kind of part is *not regulated* (at least not in any country that I can think of) and *does not modify the functioning of the gun in any way* (it's just a part that holds an electronical sight on top of the firearm), that's why I'm attempting to build this even if I have no experience in mechanical engineering.

This is what it looks like (this is one from a random manufacturer):
[image: Example of Red Dot Sight Mount]

My question is: what should be the ***minimum* thickness** of the top part (the part with a red line on the picture above) so it doesn't **break or bend/deform**? The material is 7075 Aluminum with a type 3 anodizing finish.

The main thing to take into account will probably be the recoil of the firearm (9x19mm caliber pistol) which produces a recoil of about 2.7 kg.m/s, but then I have no idea what to do with it.

Most mounts sold commercially are about 0.10in-0.15in thick but I would like to go thinner to have the sight sit lower.

I understand the answer to this question might be complex and it might not be possible to give a numerical answer without (much) more details, but could you perhaps give the method and main formulas? Or a software that could be used to run simulations?

Comment: Make it curved, but 1/10th is already fairly thin for aluminum.

Answer (score 1):

No one would design this, they would do it iteratively.  Too many variables:

- acceleration of the slide starting and stopping
- mass of the sight
- grade of aluminum
- mounting method

"Minimum" isn't a spec.  A spec is an expcted lifetime on a specific platoform.

I don't know who could actually tell the difference in a .1" vs .05" elevation of a sight other than aesthetically. And it would be easier to mill it deeper into the slide.

Comment: I think that mount is meant to slide into the rear sight dovetail.